# Is there anyway i can check the version of intel chipset installation utility?

Tags: driver, intel, device-manager

I installed Intel Chipset Installation Utility 10.0.22 Rev.A(3 Dec 2014) on my HP 430G2. But i suspect it didn't installed properly. How can i check what version my laptop currently have?

Answer (score 0):

you could download and run the driver update utility from Intel [http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect], although that might not show chipset - depending on the system.
So look in Device Manager under System Devices and then right click on your chipset and on the driver tab, check the version number.